# Using array_diff(), how to get difference from array2 instead of array1?

Tags: php, arrays, compare, array-difference

I'm trying to use array_diff like so.  Here are my two array outputs:

List 1 Output

```
Array ([0] => 0022806 )
```

List 2 Output

```
Array ([0] => 0022806 [1] => 0023199 )
```

PHP

```
$diff = array_diff($list_1, $list_2);

print "DIFF: " . count($diff) ."<br>";
print_r($diff);
```

The Output is:

```
DIFF: 0
Array ( )
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?  Why is `0023199` not returned?

Comment: What if you invert the arguments? `Returns an array containing all the entries from array1 that are not present in any of the other arrays.`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The order of arguments in array_diff() is important

> Returns an array containing all the entries from **array1** that are not
>   present in any of the other arrays

Comment: Is there a better way? I have no idea what the order may look like...I'm just interested in getting the delta between the two.

Comment: Do array_diff() both ways round, then array_merge() the results? That will give you teh entries that are in one array or the other, but not in both

Answer (score 16):

try;

```
$diff = array_merge(array_diff($list_1, $list_2), array_diff($list_2, $list_1));

print "DIFF: " . count($diff) ."<br>";
print_r($diff);
```

Answer (score 2):

[From the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php):

> Returns an array containing all the entries from array1 that are not
>   present in any of the other arrays.

If you only want to check whether they are the same, you can use `$list1 == $list_2`

Answer (score 1):

Per the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php), the values of the second array are subtracted from the first one.  Or, to put it another way, you start with the first array, and then remove all the values that appear in the second array.  That would correctly yield an empty array that you see above

You might want to play around with [intersection](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php), that might help you get what you want.